# jquery: find the index of an element that contains a given string

Tags: jquery, html

In an HTML I created a "div" with an unique id.  Within this "div" I have more "div"s, in which each contains a string.  For example:

```
<div id="name">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to find the index of a "div" that contains a string, say "A", within the "div" with id="name".

I think selector ":contains" should be used in combination with .index() but I can't figure out the right syntax.  This is what I've tried:

```
var index = $("#name"):contains(A).index("div");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
var index = $("#name>div:contains(A)").eq(0).index();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GhPxD/1/

Comment: Yep it works now, thanks!  But somehow I got a double value when I use this back on the webpage I am developing (using jquery accordion).  I divided the value returned by 2 as a temporary solution.

Comment: try it with `eq(0)` and if that doesn't work, make sure it's not being caused by extra elements being created by the accordion widget.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want

```
var index = $('#name div:contains("A")').index();
```

That will find the element matching the selector `div:contains('A')` within the element with id = name.

As you've probably worked out by now, selectors prefixed with `:` are meant to be used within the selector string. Many have corresponding jQuery functions that can be chained instead (e.g. `:eq()` and `.eq`), but `:contains()` does not (the function `.contains()` tests for DOM elements within other elements, rather than looking at text).

Comment: Ugh, you're right - `.index()` looks in the current array, rather than in children. @ilia had the right answer, so I'm updating mine as well.